Blob image in header breaks the page
I want to display in the header of the document, an image from the database. The image depends on the company being selected.
I tried every solution I found here, nothing works.
Two of them work outside the header, but inside, they either break the page, or the image is not visible.
What I am doing wrong?
$stmt_antet = $conn -> prepare ("SELECT antet FROM societati WHERE id_societate = ?");
$stmt_antet->bind_param("s",$id_societate_raport);
        
if (!$stmt_antet -> execute()) {
    echo mysqli_errno($conn);
    }
else {
    $result_antet = $stmt_antet -> get_result();
    $row_antet = $result_antet -> fetch_assoc();
        $antet = $row_antet['antet'];
    }



require_once('tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php');

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
          
      public function Header() {
       
        // this gives a broken page
    $imgdata_m = base64_decode($antet);
    $this->Image('@'.$imgdata_m, 25, 35, 160, 24, 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        
    // this gives a broken page and doesn't work outside the header either
    $antet_encoded = "data:image/png;base64,".$antet;
    $this->tcpdf->Image("@".$antet_encoded, 25, 35, 160, 24, 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
       
        
         // TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image
    $img_base64_encoded = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.$antet;
    $imageContent = file_get_contents($img_base64_encoded);
    $path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix');
        file_put_contents ($path, $imageContent);
        $img = '<img src="' . $path . '">';
    $this->writeHTML($img, 25, 35, 160, 24, 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
    
    }


// outside the header, it works just fine
$imgdata_m = base64_decode($antet);
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata_m, 25, 35, 160, 24, 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);


// outside the header, it works just fine
$img_base64_encoded = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.$antet;
$imageContent = file_get_contents($img_base64_encoded);
$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix');
file_put_contents ($path, $imageContent);
$img = '<img src="' . $path . '">';
$pdf->writeHTML($img, 25, 35, 160, 24, 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);



Two of these scripts work just fine, when they are outside the header (see comments above respective lines). I know the example 003, I've used it, it works with files on a path. What I want, is to display images that are stored in database as longblob.

How do i do that?
